# Is there a way to make a Cytoscape.js graph responsive?

Tags: cytoscape.js

What I mean by this is that if the user changes the size of the browser window, I would like the graph to re-render and fit into the new space. Currently, if I resize the window, the graph (nodes and edges) do not change size.

You can see this be resizing your browser window when viewing any of the demos, for example: [Cyctoscape.js Demo](https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/images-breadthfirst-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

The cytoscape function you're probably looking for is "cy.center".
According to [the docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.center), the function "pans the graph to the centre of a collection".

So you just have to catch the resize event and the page will automatically re-center on the graph every time the window is resized.

Result:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    cy.center();
});
```

Comment: The above code does center the graph but it cuts out the parts that were large ,it does not shrink the size of the graph. There is no explicit function to shrink and position functions are not helping me either. Any advice?